# Magento 1.9,i can't get grid with checked products

Tags: php, mysql, magento-1.9

I have created a custom module, in it I use grid products in the admin in my module. When I check products I can successfully save them to my table, but I want to have this product to load with checked rows.

How can I do it?

[image]
Here is my code:

```
$this->addColumn('is_selected', array(
        'type'      => 'checkbox',
        'name'      => 'is_selected',
        'field_name' => 'selectedproducts[]',
        'values' => $this->_getSelectedProducts(),//here i go to method
        'index'     => 'entity_id',
    ));
```

---

And bellow

```
protected function _getSelectedProducts()
    {
        $products = Mage::getModel('custom_module/mytable')->getData();//Here i need some help 
        return $products;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution for grid with serializer:

```
        protected function _getSelectedProducts(){
            $products = $this->getActionProducts();
            if (!is_array($products)) {
                $products = array_keys($this->getSelectedProducts());
            }
            return $products;
        }
        //callback method for serializer
        public function getSelectedProducts() {
            $products = array();
            $selected = $this->getRequest()->getPost('products');
            if (!is_array($selected)){
                $selected = array();
            }
            foreach ($selected as $product) {
                $products[$product->getId()] = array('position' => 
                $product->getPosition());
            }
            return $products;
        }
```